# Reflection or Regex on Custom attributes

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes, custom-attributes

I have seen [Attributes and Reflection](http://oreilly.com/catalog/progcsharp/chapter/ch18.html) and now i know how to create and use reflection to see meta data of attribute but is it possible to make a standalone tool that can analyse a `cs` file and extract attributes used ?

**What am I trying to do?**

Basically I am working on a tool which takes `C# code` as input. Next step is to see what Attributes are used in that source code. Extract `Intrinsic` and `Custom Attributes`.

**Probem?**

this makes sense if you are using `reflection` in same project in which your `attributes` are defined, however `I do not know in what direction I should move` to write a separate tool that can give you above extracted statics and meta data of attributes.

Some say I should use `Regex` to extract the attributes in files where as other say I need to use [Irony - .NET Language Implementation Kit](http://irony.codeplex.com/)

**Furthermore**

above work will result me to have an application that will be used for `attributes(annotation) based Design Pattern Recovery` from `Source Code`. I have less idea if `Regex` would come to rescue or i need something like `Reflection`. As Reflection is deals with runtime. I do not have to deal with run time. just static files analysis

Comment: I cannot understand how reflection and C# project file are both connected to your problem. If you are using reflection - you are working with already compiled executable or dll, so you don't need to parse project file. If you need to work with sources - you cannot use reflection

Comment: @Archeg file is just to read the source code and see what is implemented. Instead of reflection what should I use if i have to work with source codes ?

Comment: If you really need to parse source code, I'd look on Rosalyn. But I've never used it, so not sure will it suite you. Are you sure you need parsing source code? Why doesn't reflection suite you?

Comment: Maybe you can write something more about you task. Why do you need those attributes? For example if you need to just list all attributes used in the code, simple Regex is enough.

Comment: Pretty hard to pass up System.CodeDom.Compiler to turn a considerable task into a trivial one.

Comment: @Archeg well more detail is here which would just make it complex:). I am working `attributes(annotation) based Design Pattern Recovery` from `Source Code`. I have less idea if `Regex` would come to rescue or i need something like `Reflection` :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I properly understood your problem, you really need to parse your code. Regex won't help you, as beside parsing attributes you will need to parse class hierarchy. Reflection might do the trick, but you won't be able to show to the user the results. So, the best idea is to use any parser to get an expression tree from the source, and than investigate it.

If you don't know which parser to choose - I'd recommend Rosalyn, as it should be easiest for parsing C# code (it is designed especially for it). You can find an example for parsing here:
http://blog.filipekberg.se/2011/10/20/using-roslyn-to-parse-c-code-files/

I think it should be really powerful and useful for your task

Answer (score 2):

Apparently I don't have enough reputation to comment, so I'm gonna have to say this as an answer.

Reflection deals with Runtime Type Information.  It is a mechanism for finding out things about a type that you the programmer don't already know about (perhaps someone else is providing you a code library, and forgot to document it).  Reflection will give you any information you need about the public contract of a class, including methods, properties, fields, attributes, and interfaces/classes inherited.

What *you* need however is a parser.  A parser is a standard programming concept that processes files and extracts specific information.  You are looking for information in code files, which are not runtime types yet, which means reflection has no information on them yet, however you have your eyes, since they're still code files.  In the event your eyes are not sufficient (as I suspect their not if you asked the question) you need to write a parser.  Extracting specific information from a cs file is pretty simple.  And the regex for an attribute is: `\[.+\]`

Comment: I'm beginning to think you haven't really demonstrated what you need.  Based on what you said, simply regex matching a source file will give you a complete list of attributes declared in the source file.